# How to get absolute path of a file in clipboard in JAVA and get the location where it is pasted

Tags: java, filepath

I am fairly newbie to java. How can i get File Path i copied in clipboard and also get the location where it is pasted.
So there will be two strings one

- `String copied = "c:\\somelocation.exe"`
- `String paste= "d:\\somelocation.exe"`

I don't want it in real time, but a way by which it can detect my click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little investigation, I have found, that in **general** you cannot get an absolute path of the source file from `Clipboard`.

When you select a *small* file and copy it; clipboard contains file content and all you can to do is just read from clipboard as InputStream. In this situation, you cannot get a path of source file.

When you select a *big* file (I've tried it with a 17Gb mkv), then clipboard contains path to this file. In this case you can read clipboard and get a file path instead of it content. Once again, it depend on the file size and I do not know at what file size Windows stops copying file content and start put file path to clipboard.

Below a code snippet, when I get a `Clipboard` instance and detect two possible situations when it is possible to get source file path: when clipboard contains either `plaint string` or `list of strings`.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    String path = readAsString(clipboard);
    path = path == null ? readAsFileList(clipboard) : path;
}

private static String readAsFileList(Clipboard clipboard) {
    try {
        List<String> paths = (List<String>)clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
        return paths.isEmpty() ? null : paths.iterator().next();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private static String readAsString(Clipboard clipboard) {
    try {
        return (String)clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Unicode String
 at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getData(SunClipboard.java:220)

Comment: It means that in your `clipboard` you have a line to a file but no a string path.

Comment: Then describe what you want. My solution works if you copy a `string` with full path to a file. But not wokring when you select a file and then press copy from context menu (this is what you want?)

Comment: yes, i want when i copy a file or folder and i run my java program it should show the path of that file or folder

Comment: I have to think then. I am not sure that whey you copy a whole file, path to the source is stored into clipoard. Clipboard contains file content but not file path.

Comment: example i copied a file in c drive so, string should contain C:\\filename.exe

Comment: I have modified my answer. I how this will help you.